# Is there a perfect translation for the word tipsy in Japanese?

Tags: word-choice

I have talked to friends here and there and looked up words.

So far I have：

ほろ酔い、
生{なま}酔い、
酔{よ}いが回{まわ}る／回った、
酒{さけ}の気{け}、
微{び}醺{くん}

ちょっと酔っ払ってる

In English *tipsy* has a positive connotation so I was wondering which one would be the best fit. I feel like most of the examples I listed can be used in both a negative or positive way so if anyone any idea about this please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

ほろ酔{よ}い気{き}分{ぶん} would be my choice. Aside from the general usage, I knew someone who had that nickname. Always looked like he has halfway to falling asleep and smiling at things out of the blue, but in good spirits.

微{び}醺{くん} is more of a written form, with the same meaning as ほろ酔い. 生{なま}酔{え}い doesn't connote a feeling as much as a state halfway between sober and drunk. 酔{よ}いが回{まわ}る (The alcohol's doing it's thing) is different grammatically, so I'm not sure that's what you want. 酒{さけ}の気｛け｝ is drunk.

Aside from the reasons above, some of your examples aren't used as often as ほろ酔い. ちょっと酔ってて、いい気分だぜ。

If you have an example sentence or context in which you would use it that might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I also think that 生酔い is  なまよい not なまえい. I tried to edit it but Stack exchange requires six characters to make an edit.

Comment: なまよい is the altered pronunciation, likely because so many people had trouble with the original pronunciation. Anyhow, it is used so infrequently that it doesn't really merit debate.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks for sharing. I didn't know that! @user272